# get status 400 all the time while sending parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hello i am new all around Spring,Rest and servlets. i build an example that have a function that get 3 parameters from the user and print them in the browser.
no i run the follwoing command:

```
http://localhost:8080/springexample/getMails/setup/user/1234/matant@gmail/
```

and i get:

```
 HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'username' is not present

type Status report

message Required String parameter 'username' is not present

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

this is my code:

```
    package com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/getMails")
public class GetEmail {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/setup/{username}/{pass}/{host}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String Setup(@RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("pass") String pass,@RequestParam("host") String host ,ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {
            model.addAttribute("msg","user = "+username+","+"pass = "+pass+","+"host = "+host);
            return "helloWorld";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/displayMessage/{msg}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String displayMessage(@PathVariable String msg, ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
            return "helloWorld";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/knainz", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String knainz(ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("msg", "JCG Hello World2222!");
            return "helloWorld";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/func1/{message}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String func1(@PathVariable String message,ModelMap model) {
            model.addAttribute("msg", message);
            return "helloWorld";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing `@RequestParam` with `@PathVariable`. 
Change

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setup/{username}/{pass}/{host}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Setup(@RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("pass") String pass,@RequestParam("host") String host ,ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addAttribute("msg","user = "+username+","+"pass = "+pass+","+"host = "+host);
        return "helloWorld";
    }
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setup/{username}/{pass}/{host}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Setup(@PathVariable("username") String username,@PathVariable("pass") String pass,@PathVariable("host") String host ,ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {
        model.addAttribute("msg","user = "+username+","+"pass = "+pass+","+"host = "+host);
        return "helloWorld";
    }
```

Comment: i try this but it didnt help. now i have other problem i change my class name from "GetEmail" to "GetEmailMessages" and now i got the HTTP Status 500 error with this message "Cannot map handler 'getEmail' to URL path [/getMails/knainz]: There is already handler of type [class com.javacodegeeks.snippets.enterprise.GetEmailMessages] mapped."

Comment: Well, maybe we can solve one problem at a time. If the change to `@PathVariable` didn't worked for you, maybe you should change back your classname to what it was before and try again. If there are still issues then than comment back please.

Comment: i delete the project and create it again and now your solution is working